# Can I have a JS transform that would automatically name my anonymous functions?

Tags: javascript, debugging, reactjs, babeljs, jstransform

[JSX has a transform to add a `displayName` for a React component based on the assigned variable](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#the-transform). This means, that this code:

```
var Nav = React.createClass({ });
```

becomes this:

```
var Nav = React.createClass({displayName: "Nav", });
```

This is very nice for debugging.

I thought that it would be cool to have something similar also for ordinary JS functions (at least in development), so that I wouldn't see cryptic stacktraces like this:

I think this would be helpful in debugging, so that I would not see stacktraces like this anymore.

[image: ugly stacktrace]

To be more precise, I'd like this:

```
getInitialState: function () {
    // stuff
},
componentWillMount: function () {
    // stuff
},
```

to become this:

```
getInitialState: function getInitialState () {
    // stuff
},
componentWillMount: function componentWillMount () {
    // stuff
},
```

Can I achieve this with any of the libraries out there or do I need to write my own transform with help of [jstransform](https://github.com/facebook/jstransform), [Babel transforms](https://babeljs.io/docs/advanced/transformers/) or yet something else?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question 100%, because from my testing, the default Babel transforms already do what you ask: `let object = { test: function (a) {} }` becomes `var object = { test: function test(a) {} };`. Is this not what you wanted, or does that not happen for you? What version of Babel are you using?

Comment: That's useful information. I'm not using Babel, just Facebook's JSX transform. Would have to try Babel.

Comment: Babel will transpile JSX for you, so you can move from Facebook's JSXTransform directly to Babel without much difficulty.